# Listening for event on emoji button picker

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get something working using the emoji button code from https://github.com/joeattardi/emoji-button

Using advice from the developer of the code (https://github.com/joeattardi/emoji-button/issues/58) I have been shown how to call the emoji picker from a button, which works as per this example:

https://codepen.io/thinksInCode/pen/YzymeoM

## JS

```
const button = document.querySelector('#emoji-button');

const picker = new EmojiButton();

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  picker.togglePicker(button);
});
```

## HTML

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@joeattardi/emoji-button@3.0.3/dist/index.min.js"></script>

<button id="emoji-button">Click Me</button>
```

As you can see on the Codepen example, the picker opens when the "Cick Me" button is launched.

Unfortunately I don't know how to add in a text input field (well, I know that bit), and change the code so that when the "Click Me" button is clicked, and an emoji is clicked from the picker, that clicked emoji is inserted into the text input field.

The advice from the developer on the Github issue is:

> If you use the native emoji style, you can definitely use a text field
>   instead of a div.
>
> All you have to do is listen for the emoji event on the picker and you
>   can do whatever you want with the emoji that was picked.

That sounds simple, if you know what you're doing, which I don't! 
If anyone is able to advise how that can be done please, it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](https://codepen.io/casa90/pen/dyGPRVj) you just need to start emit with emoji event . You can read detail info in this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@joeattardi/emoji-button)

put input element into html

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

in js put this to start emit emoji event. You can use `querySelector` to find input element than add emoji to its value attribute.

```
picker.on('emoji', emoji => {
    document.querySelector('#input').value += emoji;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Well here is a working pen https://codepen.io/ehabsan/pen/GRogEve
Basically all what you have to do is add event listener on picker, and act in that listener.

so in html

```
<button id="emoji-button">Click Me</button>
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

and in js

```
const button = document.querySelector('#emoji-button');

const picker = new EmojiButton();

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  picker.togglePicker(button);
});

picker.on('emoji', emoji => {
   document.querySelector('#input').value += emoji;
});
```

Comment: That's great - thank you very much. I'd have put this as the correct answer, but pc_coder was first. Thanks again :-)